# Yosemite update problem

Tags: software-update, macos, software

Trying to update to Yosemite. Unfortunately I'm encountering the Verify File System and Repair Fail. Ive got no backup whatsoever prior to updating to the new OS. I have Windows and I can boot on that just fine. How do I solve this problem and how do I recover my files on OS via Windows.

Comment: I had this same  problem. My data is still available on the HD, but I can't boot into mavericks anymore. Is there a way, maybe, to fix the bootloader to point to the mavericks partition istead of the Yosemite one. Still trying.

Answer (score 1):

[Paragon HFS for Windows](http://www.paragon-drivers.com/hfs-windows/) (or similar) might be your only hope, plus some good disk recovery software on the PC - there is a whole slew of freebies for Windows, but I don't know how good they are. Try http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm The list of available software is constantly changing.

Even if you manage to recover any data, the file names will be gone, so you will then have to dredge through & try to add appropriate names to everything you can recognise.

**Then invest in a backup solution & remember the adage

"Any data stored in less than three separate locations ought to be considered** ***temporary***.